# Azure site slot swap from teamcity

Tags: powershell, azure, teamcity

I have a super simple script which is supposed to swap slots on a site in Azure.

It relies on the azure tools.

swap.ps1

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Services\ShortcutStartup.ps1"

Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile -PublishSettingsFile "mysubsettings.publishsettings"
Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot -Name "mysite" -Slot1 "staging" -Slot2 "production" -Force
```

If I execute this from the console (`powershell swap.ps1`) everything works perfectly.

If I execute this in teamcity I get:

```
[Step 1/1] PowerShell Executable: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
[10:05:45][Step 1/1] Working directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3de96e708f2408e
[10:05:45][Step 1/1] PowerShell arguments: [-NonInteractive, -ExecutionPolicy, ByPass, -File, swap.ps1]
[10:05:47][Step 1/1] For a list of all Azure cmdlets type 'get-help azure'.
[10:05:47][Step 1/1] For a list of Windows Azure Pack cmdlets type 'Get-Command *wapack*'.
[10:05:49][Step 1/1] Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile : The term 'Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile' 
[10:05:49][Step 1/1] is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
[10:05:49][Step 1/1] program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
[10:05:49][Step 1/1] that the path is correct and try again.
```

Its like its not loading the azure powershell correctly but I cant work out why this could be (especially given it has the output from the azure tools, lines 4,5)

I have tried using both file and source code options with the same results.

Any ideas why the exact same script would run in console but not in teamcity?

Comment: Might it be related to the "bitness" of the powershell version you are running under TeamCity? There is a dropdown in TeamCity where you can select x86 or x64. Depending on the version used, modules might or might not be loaded. Just a guess.

Comment: @DavidBrabant I tried both it didnt seem to affect it

Comment: Is it running in the console on the machine the actual build agent is installed on? What's in the shortcut PowerShell script?

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd yeah exact same machine `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found out the issue, Im not sure why it was isolated to teamcity but the problem was to do with this:

> There is a known issue with PowerShell $env:PSModulePath that can
>   occur when installing from WebPI. If your computer requires a restart
>   due to system updates or other installations, it may cause updates
>   $env:PSModulePath to not include the path where Azure PowerShell is
>   installed. If this occurs, you may see a 'cmdlet not recognized'
>   message when attempting to use Azure PowerShell cmdlets after the
>   installation or upgrade. If this occurs, restarting the machine should
>   fix the problem.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/

When I rebooted the teamcity machine everything worked correctly.